# Decomposition of functions/maps

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following result

> A map $f :X \to Y$ has a decomposition $f = g \circ p$ (where $p: X \to X/R$ and $g: X/R \to Y$),  if and only if for every $x, y \in X$ we have that $xRy \implies f(x) = f(y)$.

So if $f$ is an injection, then we need to show that $f$ can be constructed from the projection map $p$ and some other map $g$ from the quotient to $Y$.

How should I approach this? It seems that $p$ outputs the equivalence classes of $X$ and should be a bijection, but is it continuous? Wouldn't result follow immediately if $p,g$ would both be continuous bijections?

Comment: $f$ isn't a map, if $x=y$ doesn't imply $f(x)=f(y)$. Did you mean $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$? And, what is $R$?

Comment: No I meant $x=y \implies f(x) = f(y)$ and $R$ is an equivalence relation. Perhaps I should write $xRy \implies f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: Yes, that would be much better. Equivalence relation doesn't mean equality. But then where does "if $f$ is an injection" come from? and where does continuity come from? Is there a topology you aren't telling us about?

Comment: Ah, I messed up with $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$ and $x = y \implies f(x) = f(y) $. Injection shouldn't be considered here that way.

Comment: In general, $X/R$ has fewer elements than $X$, so $p$ can't be a bijection. And I still don't see how continuity comes into it.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Filippo?

Comment: Come on, Filippo – meet me halfway.

Comment: Apologies I was off the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write $x_R$ for the equivalence class containing $x$. I'm going to assume that $p:X\to X/R$ is meant to be the canonical map that takes $x$ to $x_R$.

If $xRy$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$, then we can define $g:X/R\to Y$ by $g(x_R)=f(x)$. This is well-defined, since if $x_R=z_R$ then $xRz$ so $g(x_R)=f(x)=f(z)=g(z_R)$. And we have $(g\circ p)(x)=g(p(x))=g(x_R)=f(x)$, so $g\circ p=f$.

On the other hand, if there exist $x,z$ such that $xRz$ but $f(x)\ne f(z)$, then $p(x)=x_R=z_R=p(z)$, so no matter what $g$ is we must have $(g\circ p)(x)=g(x_R)=g(z_R)=(g\circ p)(z)$, so we can't have $g\circ p=f$.

Note that this direction doesn't work if we don't assume that $p$ is canonical.